# Google Scripts to Copy Image

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

After the Google Scripts update, I tried to run one of mine and it gave me an error I can't figure out.

I am trying to copy an image that is a formula ( Example: `=image("link here")` but ever since the update it copies CellImage and does not copy the formula. I have tried a few other pieces but all seem to lead to just "CellImage" text being copied instead of the actual formula or image.

Does anyone have any ideas or know what change to implement?

```
function getItemName(CellName) {
 return SpreadsheetApp.openById('Google Sheet ID').getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange(CellName).getValue();}

function getItemImage(CellName) {
return SpreadsheetApp.openById('Google Sheet ID').getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange(CellName).getFormula();}

var item = getItem('row + column');
if (item == '') {
item = getItemImage('row + column')
}
```

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36753879

Comment: Can I ask you about the relationship between your script and your issue of `Example: =image("link here") but ever since the update it copies CellImage and does not copy the formula. I have tried a few other pieces but all seem to lead to just "CellImage" text being copied instead of the actual formula or image.`?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. I get the formula when using the code you provided, and I can set it to another cell via `setFormula`. Can you please clarify what do you mean by the `"CellImage" text`? Also, can you explain what `copy` means in this situation? Where do you want to copy the formula to? Are you using any code for that? Can you provide it? Finally, what `update` are you referring to?

Comment: Sorry everyone! I took over this code and was trying to sort through it. It looks like the error is in one of the checks not the coping. It was supposed to get an item name and if there was no name (an image) it was supposed to copy the formula instead. However, it now just copies CellImage and doesn't look for the formula. I updated the code above.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like previously you were able to check for text and if there was no text have it check for a formula with the below code.

```
function getItemName(CellName) {
 return SpreadsheetApp.openById('Google Sheet ID').getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange(CellName).getValue();}

function getItemImage(CellName) {
return SpreadsheetApp.openById('Google Sheet ID').getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange(CellName).getFormula();}

var item = getItem('row + column');
if (item == '') {
item = getItemImage('row + column')
}
```

Now you need to check if it is CellImage instead of being blank. The old script is not working properly even after changing that, but the new one I am making seems to now work properly.

```
function getItemName(CellName) {
 return SpreadsheetApp.openById('Google Sheet ID').getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange(CellName).getValue();}

function getItemImage(CellName) {
return SpreadsheetApp.openById('Google Sheet ID').getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange(CellName).getFormula();}

var item = getItem('row + column');
if (item == 'CellImage') {
item = getItemImage('row + column')
}
```